# Force information (pages) to printbibliography; change citation style

Tags: biblatex, oscola

I use the very helpful oscola-script. Unfortunately, according to the citation-style the page numbers of contributions to `@incollection` are not shown in the Bibliography. I want to stick to Oscola for many reasons, is there any chance that I can force the page numbers being printed in the bibliography? Can I change the citation style for `\printbibliography[type=incollection]`?

Here is an example (unfortunately perhaps not a minimum example since certain commands are required for the oscola script to work - my question concerns only the citation in the `\printbibliography[type=incollection]`). Any help is very much appreciated!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
           12pt,
       DIV=1,              
       footinclude=false,oneside]
      {scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=oscola,
        indexing=cite,
        backend=biber,
        ecli=yes,
        citereset=chapter,
        babel=hyphen]{biblatex}
\usepackage[splitindex,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[mono=false]{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{beramono}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{%
font=\ttfamily\mdseries,
leftmargin=3.8cm,
labelwidth=3.6cm,
labelsep=0.2cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\linespread}{1.2}
\newcommand{\oscola}{\textsc{bl-oscola}}
\newcommand{\biblatex}{\textsc{biblatex}}
\newcommand{\oscolashort}{\textsc{oscola}\nocite{oscola}}
\newcounter{egcounter}\setcounter{egcounter}{0}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
% This code from Juanjo's answer at http://www.latex-community.org
% /viewtopic.php?f=&t=1437&sid30648b3e881b9dd8c033a7ed1b1f31fd&start=10
\newlength{\boxwidth}
\newsavebox{\boxcontainer}
\newenvironment{bibexample}[1][]
{%
  \medskip\par\noindent\ignorespaces
  \marginpar{[\refstepcounter{egcounter}\arabic{egcounter}]\label{#1}}%
  \setlength{\boxwidth}{0.95\linewidth}%
  \addtolength{\boxwidth}{-2\fboxsep}
  \addtolength{\boxwidth}{-2\fboxrule}
  \begin{lrbox}{\boxcontainer}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\boxwidth}%
}
{%
  \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \colorbox{gray!30}{\usebox{\boxcontainer}}
  \par\medskip}
\newcommand{\egref}[1]{[\ref{#1}]}
\newcommand{\egcite}[1]{{\texttt{\textbackslash cite#1}}}
\newcommand\angledtext[1]{$\langle$\textit{#1}\/$\rangle$}
\usepackage[final=true,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
Test!\footnote{\cite[30]{kelsen_law_1950}; \cite[280]{rasulov_doctrine_2013}.}
\printbibliography[type=book, title={Monographs},prenote=note]
\printbibliography[type=incollection, title={Contributions to edited volumes},prenote=note]
\end{document}
```

test.bib contains:

```
@book{kelsen_law_1950,
address = {London},
title = {The {Law} of {The} {United} {Nations} {A} {Critical} {Analysis} of {Its} {Fundamental} {Problems}},
publisher = {Stevens},
author = {Kelsen, Hans},
year = {1950}
}

@incollection{rasulov_doctrine_2013,
address = {Leiden},
title = {The {Doctrine} of {Sources} in the {Discourse} of the {Permanent} {Court} of {International} {Justice}},
booktitle = {Legacies of the {Permanent} {Court} of {International} {Justice}},
publisher = {Brill},
author = {Rasulov, Akbar},
editor = {Tams, Christian J. and Fitzmaurice, Malgosia},
year = {2013},
pages = {271--317}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you add four whitspaces before each line of code so that it becomes human-readable. And your example can hardly be called minimal.

Comment: Please consider making your examples more minimal (at least for the future): Many packages that are loaded in the preamble are not needed at all to show the issue (`multicol`, `booktabs`, `geometry`, `setspace` ... to name but a few).

Comment: Can you please tell us where and in what format you would like to see the page numbers? I don't have the OSCOLA handbook handy, so I can't look up the actual rule. Ideally you would show the output you currently get from the MWE and then the output you would like to see with the page number.

Comment: If you think there should be page numbers in the bibliography, you can always open a bug report or feature request at https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/issues, from what I have read so far I'm beginning to suspect that OSCOLA is a footnote-only citation style and that there are no provisions for a bibliography list in the official guidelines, hence there is no word on page numbers for `@incollection`/`@inbook` anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses! My apologies for posting not a minimum example. To clarify: Oscola works great, the incollections are supposed to appear without pages in the bibliography, so there is no bug. My basic question is this: how can I change this? is there a way how I can customize the oscola-citation so that pages appear for incollections in the bibliography? I hoped that there was a secret command I could use in connection with printbibliography...

Comment: There is no secret method to make the pages appear. The standard way would be to modify the bibliography driver. That is not difficult *per se*, but it is easier writing an answer if I know what *exact* output you would like to see.

Comment: Let's say I wanted to have the Oscola format, just with page numbers in the end, so: Author (name, first initial of first name), 'Title of the book chapter' in editor (first initial of first name, name) (eds) \textit{title of the book} (edition, publisher year) pages            Thank you for the idea to modify the bibliography driver, I have never done this before, but I can try it (I posted the format here just in case someone can briefly post a suggestion of how such modification can look like. But again, thank you very much already! Happy holidays and all the best for the upcoming year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly OSCOLA is a style with long/full citations in the footnotes that has no provision for a bibliography at the end. Often pages are handled slightly differently in citations and the bibliography and `oscola` does not print the `pages` field at all for certain entry types.

If you want to get the pages back you need to modify the relevant drivers. The `oscola` type structure means that we need to look at `@inbook` and `@inreference`. We just add

```
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
```

in the appropriate place (the drivers can be found in `oscola.bbx`, e.g. https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/blob/1.6/oscola.bbx).

Since `oscola` does some special things for the postnote separator we need to slightly modify the `chapter+pages` bibmacro before we can use it.

```
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \ifboolexpr{
       not test {\iffieldundef{pages}}
    or not test {\iffieldundef{chapter}}}
    {\bbx@resetpostnotedelim}
    {}%
  \newunit}
\makeatother
```

Its original definition can be found in `standard.bbx` ([ll. 895-899 in version 3.14](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx#L895-L899)).

To avoid doubling of the page numbers in the footnote you may want to add

```
    citepages=suppress,
```

to the loading options. Check out the other possible values of the option in the [`verbose-inote` style documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/73-style-verbose-inote-biber.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=oscola,
        backend=biber,
        citepages=suppress,
        ecli=yes,
        babel=hyphen]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \ifboolexpr{
       not test {\iffieldundef{pages}}
    or not test {\iffieldundef{chapter}}}
    {\bbx@resetpostnotedelim}
    {}%
  \newunit}
\makeatother

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/editor/translator}%
  \newblock%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publicationinfo}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{revisedbookvolume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inreference}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publicationinfo:short}%
  \usebibmacro{revisedbookvolume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{kelsen_law_1950,
  address   = {London},
  title     = {The Law of The {United Nations}
               {A} Critical Analysis of Its Fundamental Problems},
  publisher = {Stevens},
  author    = {Kelsen, Hans},
  year      = {1950}
}
@incollection{rasulov_doctrine_2013,
  address   = {Leiden},
  title     = {The Doctrine of Sources in the Discourse of the
               {Permanent Court of International Justice}},
  booktitle = {Legacies of the {Permanent Court of International Justice}},
  publisher = {Brill},
  author    = {Rasulov, Akbar},
  editor    = {Tams, Christian J. and Fitzmaurice, Malgosia},
  year      = {2013},
  pages     = {271--317}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[30]{kelsen_law_1950}
ipsum \autocite[280]{rasulov_doctrine_2013}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> **Bibliography**
>
> Rasulov A, ‘The Doctrine of Sources in the Discourse of the Permanent Court of International Justice’ in CJ Tams and M Fitzmaurice (eds), Legacies of the Permanent Court of International Justice (Brill 2013), pp 271–317.
>
> **Citation**
>
> Akbar Rasulov, ‘The Doctrine of Sources in the Discourse of the Permanent Court of International Justice’ in Christian J Tams and Malgosia Fitzmaurice (eds), Legacies of the Permanent Court of International Justice (Brill 2013) 280.

[image: Image of the output reproduced above.]

You can move the page number around freely in the driver. If you want to move the page numbers to a position that is controlled by a bibmacro, a different approach is needed.

---

Note that you may want to hold off any LaTeX (in particular `biblatex`/Biber) updates to avoid running into https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/pull/8.

Comment: brilliant, thank you so much!!