# Modifying bibliography driver biblatex oscola

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, oscola

After I have received great help here before when I wanted to modify the bibliography driver for `@incollection` ([Force information (pages) to printbibliography; change citation style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521529/force-information-pages-to-printbibliography-change-citation-style)) it transpired that there are two last modifications which I would like to learn: they concern the way `@article` is presented in the bibliography in Oscola, namely unfortunately only with the first page instead of the page-range, and the way in which author names are cited in the bibliography, namely unfortunately with abbreviated first names.

I do not understand what I need to change in order for the whole page range being printed in the bibliography. The Oscola BBX code can be found here: https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/blob/1.6/oscola.bbx

I suspect that the reason why only the first page is printed is in line 413 (?):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{%
  \mkfirstpage*{#1}}
```

Can someone please tell me which changes I have to do, so that the entry in the bibliography reads Fauchald OK, ‘The Legal Reasoning of ICSID Tribunals - An Empirical Analysis’ (2008) 19(2) European Journal of International Law 301-364

Also, I would prefer if authors’ name do not appear in the bibliography as „Fauchald OK“, but as „Fauchald, Ole Kristian“. The same for authors of `@book` and of `@incollection`.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Here is my minimum example which includes the lines that ensure that `@incollection` items are printed in the bibliography with the whole page range (thanks to moewe, see the first link above):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=oscola,
  indexing=cite,
  backend=biber,
  citepages=suppress,
  ecli=yes,
  citereset=chapter,
  babel=hyphen]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \ifboolexpr{
      not test {\iffieldundef{pages}}
      or not test {\iffieldundef{chapter}}}
    {\bbx@resetpostnotedelim}
    {}%
  \newunit}
\makeatother

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/editor/translator}%
  \newblock%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publicationinfo}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{revisedbookvolume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inreference}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publicationinfo:short}%
  \usebibmacro{revisedbookvolume}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\addbibresource{fauchald.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[303]{fauchald_legal_2008}
Lorem \autocite[50]{koskenniemi_apology_2007}
Lorem \autocite[280]{rasulov_doctrine_2013}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Fauchald.bib contains:

```
@article{fauchald_legal_2008,
  title = {The {Legal} {Reasoning} of {ICSID} {Tribunals} - {An} {Empirical} {Analysis}},
  volume = {19},
  number = {2},
  journal = {European Journal of International Law},
  author = {Fauchald, Ole Kristian},
  year = {2008},
  pages = {301--364}
}

@incollection{rasulov_doctrine_2013,
  address = {Leiden},
  title = {The {Doctrine} of {Sources} in the {Discourse} of the {Permanent} {Court} of {International} {Justice}},
  booktitle = {Legacies of the {Permanent} {Court} of {International} {Justice}},
  publisher = {Brill},
  author = {Rasulov, Akbar},
  editor = {Tams, Christian J. and Fitzmaurice, Malgosia},
  year = {2013},
  pages = {271--317}
}

@book{koskenniemi_apology_2007,
  address = {Cambridge},
  edition = {2},
  title = {From {Apology} to {Utopia}: {The} {Structure} of {International} {Legal} {Argument} - {Reissue} {With} {New} {Epologue}},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  author = {Koskenniemi, Martti},
  year = {2007}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right in your guess about why only the first page is printed for articles in the bibliography. You can fix it by adding this to your preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
```

Normally the printing of given names as initials is controlled using the `giveninits` option for `biblatex`, but `biblatex-oscola` hard codes it. You can fix it by adding this to your preamble:

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \togglefalse{abx@bool@giveninits}}
```

We also need to add the comma in between the family name and the given names, which can be done by adding this to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

Your example (with some modifications to make it work with current versions of `biblatex`) then gives me:

[image: output]